# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable in a int object

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Here is a function to check the data and update it

**div , update are my mongodb collection object**

```
def data_updater(user1_id,code):
   device_id = dvi.find_one({"user_id":user1_id},{"_id":0,"user_id":0})["device_id"]
   prv_data = update.find_one({"device_id":device_id},{"_id":0,"device_id":0})
   prv_date = prv_data["date"]
   msg = prv_data["message"]
   if prv_date < current_date and msg != code:
      x = update.find_one_and_update({"device_id":id,},{"$set":message":code,"date":current_date}})
      print(x.acknowledged)
```

and when I am calling the function it is giving TypeError  `data_updater(95626,972681)`

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File  line 170, in <module>
    data_updater(95626,972681)
  File  line 71, in data_updater
    device_id = dvi.find_one({"user_id":int(user1_id)},{"_id":0,"user_id":0})["device_id"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I am not able to find any mistake please help

Comment: In what line it the error? what are `dvi`, `update` and the rest of the variables?

Comment: So likely, `dvi.find_one(...)` returns `None`, and you then apply a subscript `["device_id"]` on it. Check the return value of `dvi.find_one(...)` first.

Answer (score 0):

Your context isn't very clear, however, from the error trace as generated it seems that your `find_one()` function returns `None` with the arguments as passed and you are trying to access the value for the key `device_id`. I recommend you refactor your `find_one()` function or make use of the following code to resolve the issue at hand:

```python
def data_updater(user1_id,code):
    try:
        device_id = dvi.find_one({"user_id":user1_id},{"_id":0,"user_id":0})["device_id"]
        prv_data = update.find_one({"device_id":device_id},{"_id":0,"device_id":0})
        prv_date = prv_data["date"]
        msg = prv_data["message"]
        if prv_date < current_date and msg != code:
            x = update.find_one_and_update({"device_id":id,},{"message":code,"date":current_date}})
            print(x.acknowledged)
     except TypeError:
            print('No value found for specified parameters :/')
```

PS: I also didn't understand the use of `$` in your code, so I removed it thinking of it as a mistake. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help  and the $ is the syntax for changing the value in mongodb as of I know